# How can I jump directly to a specific time point in a Raphael animation?

Tags: raphael

I'm working on animating an element in [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) along a path.  I need to be able to show the element not only animated along the entire path, but also "frozen" at a specific time point. For example, if I have a circle moving from one point to another point, rotating along the way, for 5 seconds, I would like to be able to "jump" directly to show the circle after 2 seconds without having to start the animation from beginning and stopping it after 2 seconds.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what to try assuming I want to make use of the animation functions in Raphael, latest version, and not to depend upon CSS.  Do you have any idea or direction?...

Comment: It seems I will use GSAP (http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) instead of Raphael, they seem to support such functionality, and since I focus not on SVG but on animation, it seems like a good choice.